# Problem using startx on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, remote, xorg, putty

I have a problem with my raspberry. I have installed Raspbian, used the command `startx`, and it worked.

After that I configured it so I can access it over network. I used `PuTTY` to remotely access it and when I use the command `startx`, it freezes at `FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.` until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: You are trying to startx from a remote shell, but where would you like the desktop to appear?  On a monitor connected to the pi, or on the remote system?

Comment: On the remote system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the GUI on a remote machine you can use `VNC`. `tightvncserver` is available for the Pi. There are hundreds of tutorials on this.

You need `VNC` on your computer, again there are lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem. This error is not something blocking use of startx. When you use Putty (ssh client) , you won't see any X server output no matter how well your xserver is configured. after you `startx` use an Remote Desktop Protocol to connect to your Pi and get access to X.